# Вставка в столбец, отсутствующий во view Postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Пока простая табличка `select * from "common".users ;`:

```
id  oid login   password                  role

0   0   root    $2a$06$***.XLEMnb0Dm.***  web.admin 1341    0
3   0   insider $2a$06$***/mX3WLS6Y/.***  web.user  1034    0
2   0   manager $2a$06$***.EeRYN86NC/***  web.manager   545     0
```

К ней делаю `view`

```
create or replace view "api".users as
SELECT users.login,
       '***'::text AS password,
       users.group_id
FROM "common".users WHERE oid=current_setting('api.user_id');
```

И тем хочу скрыть поле `password`, но при этом чтоб оно присутствовало в схеме. Ругается что у поля нет отношения с таблицей. Если поле убрать, то ругается что нет такого поля.

Comment: Ну, в поведении всё логично и верно. Хотите безопасности - закройте поле правами доступа и оставьте права только тому кому надо. Или security definer хранимками обложиться.

Comment: @Мелкий хочется оставить возможность INSERT/UPDATE для пользователя для строк отобранных через where